# ArchiveInfo.plist has incorrect data

Tags: iphone, distribution, cfbundleidentifier

After building and archiving my application, I open up ArchiveInfo.plist that's in the folder with the app and it contains some invalid data.  The **Bundle Identifier** is misspelled.  I have looked around everywhere in my XCode project for the exact same misspelling, but cannot seem to find it.  Any help?

Comment: Did u try after Cleaning the build?

Comment: Yes I did.  I cleaned the target and then I built it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had first written the app in an old Xcode and for iOS 3 so when trying to submit it for iOS 4 it was having this problem.  I just recreated the project.